# Parse MMS content

Tags: c#, parsing, mms

I have GSM modem which gets SMS/MMS messages from users. It works good when I receive SMS. But if I receive MMS the PDU message(only user data without UDH etc.) becomes like bellow:

```
E706246170706C69636174696F6E2F766E642E7761702E6D6D732D6D65737361676500B487AF848C8298583130333630303030303730353836313330323037313032313535303031008D9083687474703A2F2F6D6D7363723A383030322F30333630303030303730353836313330323037313032313535303031008805810302A300890E802B3739303938363534353735008A808E02018D
```

Then I try to convert it to ANSI(8bit octet to ANSI symbol), so it is modified to:

```
00E70006$application/vnd.wap.mms-message000000B4008700AF0084008C00820098X103600000705861302071021550010000008D00900083http://mmscr:8002/036000007058613020710215500100000088000500810003000200A300000089000E0080+790986545750000008A0080008E00020001008D
```

Seems to me convertation is wrong! How can I convert it properly and use this kind of message? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without the spec, it is hard to know.

Comment: Where can I find this spec?

Comment: depends on your GSM modem model I guess.